# GUI for watching logs (tail and grep)

Tags: software-recommendation, log, grep, tail

Could you recommend a GUI application with powerful log watching capabilities?

Generally it would work as `tail -f` in GUI, but on top of that following features would be very useful:

- filtering out some lines based on (regular) expressions
- coloring some lines based on (regular) expressions
- interactive search
- saveable configuration easily applicable to different files
- notifications based on (regular) expressions

A similar tool on Windows is [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php) and its paid version - [BareTailPro](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Multitail is what you searching for:

it has tons of [features](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/features.html).
look here for some [screenshots](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/screenshots.php).

Also have a look at this question over there at [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/53894/colorize-monitoring-of-logs)

Comment: I like this one. I am giving it a try.

Comment: Update: this is definetely the tool I've been searching for.

Answer (score 41):

I've discovered [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/), which describes itself as:

> glogg is a multi-platform GUI application to browse and search through long or complex log files. It is designed with programmers and system administrators in mind. glogg can be seen as a graphical, interactive combination of grep and less.

It will also tail files if you enable the *Follow File* option.

Just search Ubuntu's Software Center!

Installation through command line:

```
sudo apt-get install glogg
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man.

Comment: I chose this one over Multitail as the latter is actually an ncurses GUI running inside a terminal, while glogg is a true GUI (Qt).

Comment: this one is very good: simple, fast and highlight supports.

Comment: It's a great tool unless you need Unicode characters

Comment: This tool works nicely for parsing/coloring different logs produced by software. I just wish that it would have support for plug-ins.

Comment: Having tried both, I find ksystemlog is highly superior to glogg.

Answer (score 14):

Some options are: [Swatch](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/swatch) and [KSystemLog](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ksystemlog)

There's a log viewer built into Ubuntu, which can also open any log file, called *System Log*.

Answer (score 3):

and there is lnav with colored logs and search from terminal.
https://github.com/tstack/lnav
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is also opentail:
http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=161456

This is a really nice tailer with a lot of functions

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Follow**
https://sourceforge.net/projects/follow/

simple portable java application, you can follow multiple files and drap & drop them.

Answer (score 0):

After desperately searching, then trying out `lnav` and many other log viewers for the macOS, I finally found the most powerful solution with least things to learn:

**Microsoft Excel**!

- Create a blank sheet
- Import your log file as text data and select delimiter accordingly

...Now you have all the super powers of tabular data manipulation!

Comment: Excel is quite useful and many of us using Windows at work already have it, so it is good for log file analysis, but does this also `tail` the log file, adding new data as it is logged?

Comment: @RufusVS I believe that will require some macro or scripting, if possible at all.

Comment: That's what I thought.  The original question was for a log "watcher" not log "analyzer", so Excel on its own is not sufficient.

Comment: Yeah I realize that. Landed on this question when searching for an easy-to-use log visualizer / analyzer and all of a sudden found Excel could do the job so might as well post it here just in case :)