# Text/Log Viewer that that will allow filtering by words/phrases?

Tags: log

I'm looking for a GUI-based text/log viewer that will allow to only display lines that contain particular phrases/words/characters. The logs may not necessarily by OS related but from 3rd party applications.

Comment: Lots of good suggestions for you to try in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20173/gui-for-watching-logs-tail-and-grep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion is "glogg", it's available as an Ubuntu package and doesn't have nasty dependencies (Qt4-based).

Another one is ksystemlog, not sure if it does filtering as you require.

Finally I have to ask, why does it have to be GUI? Personally I'd use the old:

```
tail -f $LOGFILE |grep particular-phrase
```

there's also swatch which is possibly nicer, though I have never used it.