# How to setup ksystemlog to open any *.log file by default?

Tags: log

I've used glogg for a while and was happy with it, but it cannot show unicode characters properly.

I found ksystemlog in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20173/gui-for-watching-logs-tail-and-grep). It seem just what I need.
It can open any log file from within its open file menu, and properly display unicode characters.

Every time I need to open a different log file arriving randomly.
But I could not find any way to set it as default for `"open with.."` command. 
I could only find ways to set specific log files as default.
`"Open with"` always ignores the file I try to open.

I've tried adding "open with" command: `ksystemlog %U`, no luck.
I've tried creating a desktop file for it, but I probably doing it wrong.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved this, hope it will help someone. 
Since `ksystemlog` limitation is that it is able to open only a pre-defined files, I decided to copy the log to a temporary file and define `ksystemlog` to always open this file.

This is how it's done:

1) create a bash script (called it alog.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $1 /home/(user)/tmp.log
ksystemlog
```

2) add a desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Name=klogger
Exec=alog.sh %u
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
MimeType=text/x-log;
```

3) set `"open with"` the .desktop above script

4) in ksystemlog settings select an option to always start with the above `tmp.log`